# Import data file from Sharepoint in Qlik Sense

Tags: excel, sharepoint, qliksense

How do I import my excel data file, which is uploaded into my SharePoint folder, in Qlik Sense?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is probably to [map your SharePoint document library as a network drive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=map%20sharepoint%20drive) and then select the file to load in the normal way.